# Using Alacritty to write LaTeX (with vim) can't launch Evince to preview

Tags: 20.04, vim, latex, evince

I use Neovim to write LaTeX files with the Alacritty terminal. After writing the files I want to preview them with Evince. However, Evince doesn't launch. I don't know why. If I use the default terminal, it works!

In Neovim I use [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) or [vim-latex-live-preview](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview) to preview. Both of them work well in the default terminal but not in Alacritty.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Details needed - Ubuntu version? Versions and origins of all the tools used also needed.

Comment: ubuntu version : 20.04

using "sudo snap install alacritty --classic" to install alacritty 0.8.0.

alacritty version : 0.8.0 (a1b13e6)

Comment: Your question is still not reproducible. Please specify how all the tools were installed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't know for sure because I don't use snaps, but your problem might be due to the fact that you're using `alacritty` as a snap. The sandboxing might be preventing you from running `evince`.

I've installed `alacritty` from source and it's quite easy. Might be worth a shot.